# JMeter Graph - Why Response Times Lower When There are More Threads

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am doing the performance testing using Apache JMeter 5.0 with following thread group settings:
**Number of Threads (users) = 100**

**Ramp-Up Period (in seconds) = 5**

**Loop Count = 1**

However, I noticed that the response time is getting lower when the number of threads are increasing.

Can help to explain or guide on what happening here?

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for this, straight-ahead I can assume following ones:

1. You're firing the same requests and your application [caches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) the response and returns it directly from memory or disk instead of processing. If this is the case - consider [parameterizing your JMeter test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide) in order to send different or unique requests.
2. Your test duration is too low and application cannot ["warm-up"](https://www.jan-v.nl/post/warming-up-your-app-service) immediately. Consider longer ramp-up period
3. Your test duration is too low so you never reach 100 concurrent users, try setting Loop Count to "Forever" and limit your test duration via `Scheduler` section of the Thread Group or using [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller)
4. Your application is capable of [auto-scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoscaling) and it automatically gets higher virtual hardware specifications or extra cluster nodes via i.e. [k8s](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/). Consider setting up monitoring what happens on the application under test side using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)